# Effective clearing of vector memory

Tags: c++

Well I am creating a vector like this

```
vector<Member*> emp;
```

Then I am creating heap objects of the member class like this

```
Member* memObj = new Member();
```

Then using push_back like this

```
emp.push_back(memObj);
```

Well after using all my functions do I have to clear the memory by iterating like this ?

```
for( vector<Member*>::iterator iter = emp.begin();
                iter != emp.end(); )
{
    Member* mem = *iter;
    iter = emp.erase (iter); 
    delete mem;
    //iter++;
}
```

Is there any effective way other than iterating through each value? clear function calls the destructor only and it clears the values but does not free the memory..I wish to achieve polymorphism here...I am new in C++ ....please help..Thanks in advance.. :)  I am **not** using C++11

Comment: Why use pointers? Why not just use `std::vector<Member>` and let the vector manage all the memory itself?

Comment: Is `Member` a base or a derived class?

Comment: The optimizer may remove the call to `erase`, you may have to take extra measures if you want the call to survive.

Comment: I have to use pointers here. And I have C++ 98 with VS2005

Comment: Then you're kind of SOL. Btw, you have a bug in your code above. `iter++` shouldn't be there. `emp.erase()` already returned ana repositioned iterator. You're skipping every-other pointer and probably leaking memory. Worse, it will invoke undefined behavior if there is an odd number of items in the list.

Comment: Not completely SOL. There is always `boost::shared_ptr`. There's also the possibility that you can update your compiler. Why, exactly, are you using VS2005?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Totally!. I'm not normally a boost fan because so much of what people *used to* use it for is in the standard library now. but for someone with an ancient VS, that is a *stellar* idea.

Comment: If the ancient VS will compile boost, that is

Comment: Situations has forced me to work with the older versions...and after reading all the recommendations it turns out that there is no other way to clear the memory :( other than iterating

Comment: @WhozCraig...bug with iter fixed. +1

Comment: @WhozCraig "I'm not normally a boost fan because so much of what people used to use it for is in the standard library now." Wouldn't that be an argument for using boost libs and not waiting for the standard library to catch up? And unless you are working with a very memory-constrained target environ, boost isn't too expensive a dependency no?

Comment: @Pradhan A project at work was royally bent over upon boost changing their serialization format a few of years ago. Tis the price you pay for coding outside the standard-backed behavior box. To each their own. Some people embrace that edge heavily. Some can't afford to. I'm the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are able to use a C++11 compiler, you can use one of the smart pointers.

[`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Member>> emp;
```

or

[`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Member>> emp;
```

**EDIT**

If you are not able to use a C++11 compiler, VS 2005 is definitely too old to support C++11, you will have to delete the objects manually, like you have shown.

However, I would add a helper class to help with `delete`ing the `Member` objects.

```
struct MemberDeleteHelper
{
    MemberDeleteHelper(std::vector<Member*> emp) : emp_(emp);

    ~MemberDeleteHelper()
    {
       for( vector<Member*>::iterator iter = emp.begin();
                iter != emp.end(); ++iter )
       {
          delete *iter;
       }
    }

    std::vector<Member*>& emp_;
};
```

and use it as:

```
vector<Member*> emp;
MemberDeleteHelper deleteHelper(emp);
```

With this in place, the elements of `emp` will be deleted no matter how you return from the function. If an exception gets thrown from a nested function call, the stack will be unrolled and the elements of `emp` will still be deleted.

**EDIT 2**

Do not use `auto_ptr` objects in `std::vector`. The pitfalls of using `auto_ptr` in STL containers are discussed at http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13606 (Thanks are due to @pstrjds for the link).

Comment: Probably good to point out that if you are not using a C++11 compiler DO NOT user `auto_ptr` in a std::vector

Comment: @pstrjds, I have never used `auto_ptr`. I don't know the pitfalls of using them in `std::vector`. If you can point me to a link, I will be more than happy to include that in my answer. You are welcome to add that info to the answer too.

Comment: I am using older version of C++ . :( with VS2005

Comment: @RSahu - Here is a link discussing it.  It has to do with the copy and assignment semantics of auto_ptr.  http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13606

Comment: @RSahu... So the final decision is iterating and deleting manually right? So I guess there is no other way. Thanks for the optimization with the deleteHelper.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your intent is to added instances of types derived from `Member` to the `vector`, there's no need for `vector<Member*>`, just use `vector<Member>`.

If you actually need dynamic allocation, use `vector<unique_ptr<Member>>`. The smart pointer will automatically `delete` the instances when you `clear()` the `vector`. If this is the case, don't forget that `Member` needs a `virtual` destructor.

Similar options for pre-C++11 compilers are `std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<Member>>` or [`boost::ptr_vector<Member>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

---

Finally, your current code has a bug. `vector::erase` returns a pointer to the next element, so by manually incrementing the iterator within the loop, you're skipping every other element. And I don't understand why you're going through the trouble of storing the pointer in a temporary variable. Your loop should be

```
for( vector<Member*>::iterator iter = emp.begin(); iter != emp.end(); )
{
    delete *iter;
    iter = emp.erase(iter);
}
```

or just delete all the elements first and then clear the `vector`

```
for( vector<Member*>::iterator iter = emp.begin(); iter != emp.end(); ++iter)
{
    delete *iter;
}
emp.clear();
```

Comment: @Praetorian...Thanks for the bug fix. Updated the same